# Python POST request not returning data from backend

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, python-requests

Originally I was scraping this webpage normally, but it has been recently updated so that now my requests returns Javascript within the body of the HTML. Anyway, I've decided to alter my code so that data is being pulled via a POST request to the backend instead.

The page I'm trying to scrape is https://www.tesco.ie/groceries/en-IE/shop/fresh-food/fresh-fruit/all?page=1&count=48, and my code looks like this:

```
import json
import requests

headers = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) '
                          'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                          'Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/112.0.1722.64',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        }


payload = {
    "resources": [
        {"type": "appState",
        "params": {},
        "hash": "8608229003782371"},

        {"type": "trolleyContents",
        "params": {},
        "hash": "2574718136506441"},

        {"type": "productsByCategory",
        "params": {
            "aisle": "all",
            "department": "fresh-fruit",
            "query": {
                "count": "48",
                "page": "1"},
            "superdepartment": "fresh-food"
        },
        "hash": "4571228679394986"}
    ],

    "sharedParams": {
        "superdepartment": "fresh-food",
        "department": "fresh-fruit",
        "aisle": "all",
        "referer": "/groceries/en-IE/shop/fresh-food/fresh-fruit/all?page=5&count=48",
        "query": {
            "count": "48",
            "page": "1"
        }
    },
    "requiresAuthentication": "false"
}

server_url = 'https://www.tesco.ie/groceries/en-IE/resources'

with requests.Session() as s:

    data = s.post(
        server_url,
        headers=headers,
        data=json.dumps(payload)
    )
    print(data)
```

This code returns <Response [500]>, which I know is just the server not fulfilling my request, but I'm unsure why. My payload is a direct copy of the Request Payload from the webpages XHR on load up. I'm not very well versed in this, so I'm wondering if there's anything I'm missing?

Apologies if it's just something simple I'm missing. I appreciate any help!

Comment: I reproduced the error by using another tool so it's not a python specific problem. Looking at the exchange from the browser, I see some cookies related stuff. I wonder if they need to be handled.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback! Would you even know how I could begin looking at how to handle cookies?

Comment: I did not try, but I would try fetching a regular page, get the cookies, and attach them to the POST requests after. As for how to do that with requests: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/?highlight=cookies#cookies

Comment: Thanks @Finch_Powers, I've made some ground looking into the cookies side of things, but I think there may be some csfr token stuff I have to deal with also.